# ASP.NET, a few questions regarding making GridViews and Multiviews more user friendly

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, gridview, postback, multiview

This is kind of a mixed bag of questions, wasn't sure how to title it but here are my main queries:

1. I have a page that contains a gridview and a multiview. Once a row is selected on the gridview, a form in the multiview is then filled with the row's values. How do I make it so that when I navigate between the views of the multiview (I have 3), the page does not refresh and go to the top? It's annoying to have to scroll back down to see the multiview each time you press a button to navigate through it. I was thinking of putting an ID in the markup code but the button doesn't actually refresh the page it just executes the NextView command.
2. Every view in the multiview has a "save" button that saves the changes. After saving, the changes don't reflect in the gridview until you refresh the page completely. The values in the multiview don't update because the gridview doesn't refresh. Is there a way to have the values in the gridview change and thus correctly filling in the multiview? Would it also be possible to maintain that gridview's page, so that the table is refreshed but the user doesn't have to sift through all the pages to get back to the row in question?
3. Would it be possible to add a scroll bar to a GridView if it surpasses a certain height or width, to fit larger tables into a smaller area?

Most of the issues I have are with post-back refreshing stuff. Since a chunk of my system is based around editing with gridviews and forms, it's very annoying to have to refresh then sift through a paginated gridview just to go back to the row that was edited. Sorry for so many questions! They are all tied together by ASP.NET so I figured having them all in one post would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Page has property MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true; which should do the trick
2. Try call databind on gridview and listview, when save button is clicked and changes saved. However, it depends on how you have implemented data loading and binding.
3. You can put gridview inside div with following style: "width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll". If you need header fixed and just content scrollable, its slightly more complicated, but there is couple of tutorials available, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614041/GridView-with-Fixed-Header-and-Scroll-Bar

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the comments. For 2, the data is bound from a data source set to automatically populate the gridview when it loads. I've run into issues in the past trying to manually bind data, ASP would throw an error saying "cannot manually bind data when automatic data binding is set" or something of the sort. I will get back to you on this but the other 2 solutions are just what I needed. Kudos!